# Rails 4 + Friendly_id gem: How to generate slug with a specific string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an app that uses the globalize gem. I'm trying to add the Friendly ID gem for permalinks.

My `Product` table doesn't actually have a `name` column. The `name` column is stored in `Product::Translation`, so I can't use the `friendly_id :name, use: :slugged` set up that they recommend in the github page.

I want to set the permalink to the `name` attribute of the english translation. This is what I have so far:

```
before_save :update_slug

def update_slug
  english_translation = translations.find { |t| t.locale == :en }
  self.slug = english_translation.name if english_translation
end
```

However, this doesn't convert the english_translation.name variable to a parameter friendly format. If I have the name as `something sdfsdfs sdfsf`, the slug will be the same and that would break things since the path would be `/products/something sdfsdfs sdfsf` with all the spaces.

Is there a method I can run to convert a string into slug format? Something like:

```
before_save :update_slug

def update_slug
  english_translation = translations.find { |t| t.locale == :en }
  self.slug = slugify(english_translation.name)
end
```

I need a method that I can run manually with a parameter to generate the slug.

Comment: Why not create a delegate method called `Product#name` that returns the English translation name? Or maybe create a method called `Product#slug_name` that does this?

Comment: So you're saying `friendly_id :my_english_slug_name, use: :slugged` and define a method called `my_english_slug_name` that returns the english_translation name?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Can you post the code for your model when you tried `friendly_id :my_english_slug_name, use: :slugged`? If you still had the before_save calling update_slug then I imagine it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Friendly_ID**

As `Greg Burgardt` said, your goal is to get the value into `friendly_id`, allowing it to build your slug.

Your method is to try and manually create the `slug` attribute - you'll be much better taking the value you derive from the `translation` and passing it into friendly_id. To do this, here is what I'd do:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend Friendly_ID
   friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

   def name
      english_translation = translations.find { |t| t.locale == :en }
      english_translation.name
   end
end
```

Friendly_ID [builds your slug](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb), meaning you don't want to create the `slug` yourself:

> Since UUIDs are ugly, FriendlyId provides a "slug candidates"
>   functionality to let you specify alternate slugs to use in the event
>   the one you want to use is already taken. For example:
>
> ```
> class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
>   extend FriendlyId
>   friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged
>
>   # Try building a slug based on the following fields in
>   # increasing order of specificity.
>   def slug_candidates
>     [
>       :name,
>       [:name, :city],
>       [:name, :street, :city],
>       [:name, :street_number, :street, :city]
>     ]
>   end
> end
>
> r1 = Restaurant.create! name: 'Plaza Diner', city: 'New Paltz'
> r2 = Restaurant.create! name: 'Plaza Diner', city: 'Kingston'
>
> r1.friendly_id  #=> 'plaza-diner'
> r2.friendly_id  #=> 'plaza-diner-kingston'
> ```
>
> To use candidates, make your FriendlyId base method return an array.
>   The method need not be named `slug_candidates`; it can be anything you
>   want. The array may contain any combination of symbols, strings, procs
>   or lambdas and will be evaluated lazily and in order. If you include
>   symbols, FriendlyId will invoke a method on your model class with the
>   same name. Strings will be interpreted literally. Procs and lambdas
>   will be called and their return values used as the basis of the
>   friendly id. If none of the candidates can generate a unique slug,
>   then FriendlyId will append a UUID to the first candidate as a last
>   resort.

Comment: Thinking about this now, I'd recommend creating a `default_name` method which assumes the language is English. Then the `name` method could choose the translation for the "current language" and FriendlyId could use the `default_name` method to generate the slug. That would give you more flexibility without assuming the "name" of a product must be in English.

Answer (score 3):

I guess for the sake of posterity:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  friendly_id :default_slug, use: :slugged

  def default_slug
    english_translation = translations.find { |t| t.locale == :en }
    english_translation.try(:name)
  end
end
```